# Multiple domain / multisite file mapping using modrewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, multiple-domains, http-host

Hi I am looking for some help with properly using a rewrite rule for mod_rewrite with my application. I have multiple domains pointing to the same file structure on my server since I am using a custom php script to display the correct content per domain.

Now I want to be able to map part of file structure that does not point to a script so I can have files delivered via a shorter easier to access file path htaccess

So I want to use `domain.com/file/example.jpg` instead of `domain.com/file/specific_folder_for_this_domain/example.jpg`

I have tried this so far with no luck

```
RewriteRule ^file/(.*)$ file/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

When I looked the mod_rewrite log on my test server I found it was looping through the %{HTTP_HOST} variable for some reason and internal paths to files came out looking something like
`/home/www/domain.com/file/domain.com/domain.com/domain.com/domain.com/example.jpg` which obviously doesn't exist anywhere on my server so there are 500 errors being logged. Does anyone know how to properly set up this sort of domain mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILE} !-f
RewriteRule ^file/(.*)$ file/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```